# Problems with charset, russian letters

Tags: php, oop, pdo, character-encoding

I have a problem with charset. When im inserting values to table in russian letters it appears like this - Р?РІР°РЅ.

This is my Database connection class.

```
class Database { 

    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = '';

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }
    function connect() {
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=university', $this->user, $this->password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES CP1251'));
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
    }

    function selectQuery( $sql ) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    function insertQuery( $sql ) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Yes i know, i dont have prepared statements there, ill do it after i fix the problem. As you see in db connection i wrote `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES CP1251')`. It fixed the problem of displaying values from db(it was displayed same way). My sql is something like this :

```
$q = $this->db->insertQuery("INSERT INTO students (id,first_name,second_name,last_name,course) VALUES ('','Иван','Иванян','Иванович','1')");
```

In table its displayed like this - Р?РІР°РЅСЏРЅ
My all files are set UTF 8 without BOM. whats wrong here?

EDIT: Also all rows in tables are in utf8_general_ci

Comment: So what encoding is the data you send to the database in?

Comment: As of 5.3.6 the charset is part of DSN .. also, why the hell are you using emulated prepares? I would strongly recommend for you to consult [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). Oh, and your `Database` class is leaking encapsulation. Then again, I still cannot understand why people try to make so magic wrappers for PDO.

Comment: Teresko, i'm not sure what are you talking about.

Comment: I think it goes in cp1251, but all files are utf8 without bom, and the table is utf8_general_ci

Comment: Teresko, i have looked your url, i havent found answer on my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your database class makes no sense because you aren't using prepared statements properly. And even don't return anything from select query. And such a class makes very little sense overall.

Р?РІР°РЅ. is utf-8 encoded text shown as single-byte encoding. So, you have to add

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

to your PHP files.

Comment: you have to change set names back to utf8 as well